# udp (boost::asio) read error after async_receive_from

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

The handler sometimes gives an error after the remote UDP socket closes, the error is --> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

My question is: isn't UDP connection-less ? does it care whatever on the remote side ?

btw, I got this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

UDP is a connectionless protocol.

The confusing error message is the result of `asio` having to provide portable errors.  Some context is loss when having to go from platform specific errors to portable errors.  In this case, `asio` receives [`ERROR_PORT_UNREACHABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#error_port_unreachable) and maps it to `boost::asio::error::connection_refused`.